# Margins with Repsonsive Layout

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm pretty sure this is fairly easy, but i'm stumped.

I am working on a responsive layout design. Regardless of the size of the page, I always want there to be a 10px margin on the left and a 10px margin on the right. I am able to achieve the 10px margin on the left, but I can't figure out the right margin. How would I do this with css? I can estimate the % width based how much space I want on the right, but obviously as the page size scales so does this margin. How do I always keep margin-right? Here is an example of my code:

```
form {
width: 100%;
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-right: 10px;
    }
```

'form' sits inside '#wrap' and '.left'  all of which have the same margin-right applied:

```
#wrap {
width: 95%;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-left: auto;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #CCC;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px#CCC;
box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #CCC;
background-color: #fff;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
}

.left {
float: left;
text-align: left;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-left: 18px;
font-weight: lighter;
font-size: 12px;
color: #777777;
padding-top: 10px;
width: 100%;
margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: maybe you could just add padding on the parent element.

Comment: If the current answers aren't helping, a JSFiddle with your current situation will help find an answer a lot.

Comment: Thank you all. I've updated my code with a little more information. I'll give the JSFiddle a try...

Answer (score 0):

This will do the magic:

```
form {
  width: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: If you will provide jsfiddle or any other example that people can play with you will have better chance to get meaningful advice.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the form ends up being 100% the width of its parent container plus the 20px for the two margins.

It would be easier to set the form inside a parent element and put padding on that. e.g.

```
body{
 padding:0px 10px;
}

form {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, my '#wrap' does have padding that it sits inside (I updated my code above) but it doesn't seem to hold it. I'll look into that some more though, it sounds like my #wrap could be the problem.

Comment: Can you put some more of your code into a fiddle? then I can see exactly what is happening